# "Of which many" vs "many of which" as parenthetical modifiers

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, modifiers

> The houses on Canal street, of which many had been damaged in the storm, looked abandoned.

Is the modifier "of which many... storm" correct?

I know that "on canal street" is a prepositional phrase so it cannot be the antecedent of "which".
also, I can say that "of which many... storm" is a subgroup modifier which modifies "houses."

But I doubt whether the modifier is properly used. My friend suggested this:

> The houses on canal street, many of which had been damaged in the storm, looked abandoned.

Although I know that this is correct and more appropriate, I cannot figure out what is wrong with the original sentence.

Is the modifier "of which many... storm" correct or not, and why so?

Comment: How about - "Many storm damaged houses on Canal street looked abandoned."

Comment: There is nothing more correct or appropriate about either of these versions. They are both grammatically, semantically, and idiomatically fine.

Comment: As JBJ notes, both versions are grammatical etc. IMO the first (with “of which many”) is a better-sounding sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would have said the same as your friend. Though, both solutions are grammatically possible.

Without the relative clause, you would have two sentences.

> The houses on Canal street looked abandoned. Many of them had been damaged in the storm.

The use of a relative clause turns "many of them" into "many of which" or also "of which many".

> The houses on Canal street, many of which had been damaged in the storm, looked abandoned.

or:

> The houses on Canal street, of which many had been damaged in the storm, looked abandoned.

Comment: delving deep, can you tell me why "many of which" is preferred to "of which many"? what's the make or break difference between those two?

Comment: I would say it is merely because we are more used to "many of which", it sounds more rounded to us.